# How do i detect special/formatting characters on either side of a character in r?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Let us say I have a string:

```
c <- "This is to inform you that you are being promoted because of good \r\nform form\r\n \r\nform\r\n recently"
```

What I want to do is to replace form with say "quality" to get the output as follows.

```
"This is to inform you that you are being promoted because of good \r\nquality quality\r\n \r\nquality\r\n recently"
```

Right now I am trying this:

```
gsub("form\\b|\\bform", "quality", c)
```

It gave output as follows.

```
"This is to inquality you that you are being promoted because of good \r\nquality quality\r\n \r\nquality\r\n recently"
```

So you see it also replaced "form" of "inform" too. This I do not want. So, now instead of detecting space on either side I want to detect special/formatting characters on either side of the string. I am not able to come up with the regex for this.

How do I do this?

PS: \r\n represent line breaks and new lines respectively.

Comment: Why do you r line breaks have the wrong slash? They should be `\r\n`. If they were correct then `gsub("\\bform\\b", "quality", c)` would work properly.

Comment: Sorry. Put wrong slash while typing. Corrected. But still does not work.I checked. It replaces form in "inform" too. Why would you say it will work? \b should detect space on either side and 'form' in 'inform' perfectly qualifies for that!

Comment: Did you use the updated `gsub` i supplied as well? When i run `c <- "This is to inform you that you are being promoted because of good \r\nform form\r\n \r\nform\r\n recently"; gsub("\\bform\\b", "quality", c)`; it does not change "inform"

Comment: I am trying this `"form\\b|\\bform"` not this `"\\bform\\b"`. Turns out mine format fails but not yours in this particular case. Thanks! But still if you could suggest a separate `regex` for this particular case, that would be helpful too!

Comment: What's wrong with `\\bform\\b`? I'm not sure why you have the form you do. Your regexp will match "inform" but not "information" Your regex looks for words that begin or end with "form", mine looks just for the word "form".

Answer (score 1):

The simple search expression `\bform\b` works if the string on which it is applied contains carriage return and linefeed in the string as displayed below:

```
This is to inform you that you are being promoted because of good 
form form

form
 recently
```

But this expression would not work if the string on which the expression is applied contains literally "\r" and "\n" and the string value is therefore

```
This is to inform you that you are being promoted because of good \r\nform form\r\n \r\nform\r\n recently
```

For such a string the search expression `(?:(?<=\\r|\\n)|\b)form\b` can be used to find the **word** *form* either after the string "\r" or the string "\n" (defined with `\\r` respectively `\\n` in an R string) or anywhere else in the text as entire word.